# I am trying to write a nested if formula with 3 columns AND 3 conditions

Tags: excel, nested

```
A   B      C    FORMULA
Y   TBC     N   ?
```

I want a formula to have all these 3 columns with each having different combination

For eg if a,b,c = Y , the result should be ABC, if a & b is Y, result will be AB and similarly "AC", "BC", "A", "B", "C"

If all three are N, the result will be N and if one is "TBC" and other 2 are N the result is TBC

Answer (score -1):

The easiest, messiest solution would be this:

```
=IF(AND(OR(A1="TBC", B1="TBC",C1="TBC"), A1<>"Y", B1<>"Y", C1<>"Y"),"TBC", IF(AND(A1="N",B1="N",C1="N"), "N", IF(A1="Y", "A", "") & IF(B1="Y", "B", "") & IF(C1="Y", "C", "")))
```

Of course, if you wanted to expand the number of columns or similar, this quickly becomes very messy, so there are more efficient ways.

Long story short, the three functions you're using in this are `IF`, `OR` and `AND`.

```
=IF(<Condition>, <What it will return if comparison is true>, <What it will return if comparison isfalse>)
=OR(<Condition>, <Condition>,...) Will be true if one or more of the Conditions are true
=AND(<Condition>, <Condition>,...) Will be true, only if all of the Conditions are true
```

In our first `IF` we want to know if any of our cells have at least one "TBC" AND the rest "N". I simplified this to At least one "TBC" and no "Y", if this isn't exactly what you want, then there are other ways to do it (If you're using Excel 2013 you can replace the `OR` with `XOR` which will return true only if exactly one of the conditions are true).

To solve this, we use

```
AND(OR(A1="TBC", B1="TBC",C1="TBC"), A1<>"Y", B1<>"Y", C1<>"Y")
```

Which is the same as saying, return true if at least one of A, B and C are "TBC" AND None of them are "Y". If this is true, then it will set the cell to "TBC", otherwise it will go on to ask the second if statement, which uses the formula:

```
AND(A1="N",B1="N",C1="N")
```

This is even simpler. It will return true if All three cells are equal to N. If it is true, it will give us the value "N" from the second argument in the `IF` Statement, otherwise it will go onto one last section:

```
IF(A1="Y", "A", "") & IF(B1="Y", "B", "") & IF(C1="Y", "C", "")
```

The other thing you need to know is the concatenate function which uses the `&` character. What this does is join together the surrounding strings.

Each `IF` will give us either a single character (the row letter) if it's true, or a blank string if it's not, so for example, if the cells have the value `Y, Y, N` then that statement will produce the strings:

```
"A" & "B" & ""
```

Which when joined together give us AB like we'd want.

Comment: @pnuts I understand that it doesn't exactly give what he asked, but since he didn't specify what should happen in cases where there are Two or more "TBC" I made the assumption I mentioned above. If it is an issue, it can be fixed in Excel 2013 by replacing `OR` with `XOR`. If 2013 isn't available, then it starts getting messy, and the lookup table is looking like a better and better solution.

Comment: OK, fair enough. I'll leave the formula here in case it points THEM in the right direction. And Sam, apologies for any mix-up of gender, personally as a Samuel, it can be confusing sometimes.